# Can't connect to Local LAN when connected to Android Phone's Internet

Tags: connection, android

I'm on my work PC connected to my work LAN, which I use to connect to Sourcesafe and MSSQL servers. However, when I tether my Android phone (through PDANet or otherwise) to my PC through USB, my connection to the LAN disappears. I do gain access to the internet though (which is how I'm posting this right now).

~Help appreciated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ultrasawblade's answer will work (if your company has a VPN), but do you really want to drag all your local traffic (Sourcesafe and MSSQL etc.) through your Android phone (3G connection?).  Ouch.

What you need to do is configure your two internet interfaces (wired(?) connection to LAN, USB-tethered WAN connection) to use different IP ranges and routes.

You don't mention what kind of system you're using (Windows?), so it's hard to give specific instructions, but basically you need to remove the default gateway from the interface which is connected to the LAN, and then configure the routing table to route LAN traffic away from your phone and through the correct interface.  [Here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Making-Sense-Windows-Routing-Tables.html) is a good article about windows routing tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need a VPN to make that work.  If your company allows access to the lan via a VPN, you can set up the VPN connection on the Android.